# Mockito doesn't work with custom validator in Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, springmockito

I am using Mockito to test one of my get-mappings in the controller class. Here is my get method

```
 @PostMapping(value = "insert/carbooking")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> reservation(@Valid BookingRequest bookRequest) {
        return validate(bookRequest, carService::booking);
    }
```

At the top of my class is my Validator

```
  @Autowired
  private ReservationValidator reservationValidator;

  @InitBinder("bookRequest")
    protected void bookRequestBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(reservationValidator);
    }
```

Here is the Mockito test method. The result should have returned bad request  since the sin is in wrong format.

```
@Test
    public void reservationTest2() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("insert/carbooking")
                .param("license", "data")
                .param("SIN", "202007191517")
                .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
```

But the test fail

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<200>
Expected :400
Actual   :200
```

Is there any way for the Mockito to receive the "reservationValidator" ?

Comment: You didn't show how you're acquiring `mockMvc`. Don't use `standaloneSetup` since it has exactly these kinds of problems (not accurately reflecting a "non-standalone" environment).

Comment: ```
 @InjectMocks
 private CarController carController;
      
 @BeforeEach
 public void setUp() {
              mockMvc = standaloneSetup(clientController)    .addPlaceholderValue("insert/carbooking", CAR1_ENDPOINT)
}
```
How do i fix that ?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? (Note also, avoid using field injection on anything but tests; use constructor injection instead to avoid all sorts of bugs.)

Comment: Yep i am using Spring Boot

Comment: Then use `@SpringBootTest @AutoConfigureMockMvc` and `@Autowired MockMvc`

Comment: Thank you! It worked as the way i want. However, when i use the method

Comment: mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("insert/carbooking")
                .param("license", "data")
                .param("SIN", "2020")
                .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                .andExpect(status().isOK());
 verify(carService, times(1)).reservation(dxo);
Now I received the error which didnt happen with the standalone setup
Wanted but not invoked:
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: You may need to use something like `@MockBean` (I use Spock, which has a slightly different setup for inserting mocks as Spring beans).

Comment: @kungho Please update your question with information you have provided in comments and also share the complete junit class.

Answer (score 0):

I got everything fixed thanks to @chrylis-onstrike- . For the source code,  I just need to remove `@Before` addholders set up method and replace it with the annotation `@Autowired` on `Mockmvc mockmvc` and `@MockBean` on service class which put the client class on the application context. It's such a shame I could not give tick mark to his answer since he didn't  post the answer to my question rather commenting on it.